# Laravel improve Code for checking Userstatus

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my application I can mark a user as blocked. After a blocked mark he can't do anything.

My solution was to check the status in every construct controller and if the authenticated user is marked as blocked he will redirect to the view.

But my solution isn't very good because i have dublicated code and i have to check for the actual route.

Here is my code:

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next)
    {
        $this->user= Auth::user();
        if(strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(),  'user.password.show') != 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(),  'user.password.set') != 0)
            {

                if(strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(),  'user.blocked.show') != 0)
                {
                    if($this->user->status == Userstatus::where('type', 'passwordSetFalse')->first()->id)
                    {
                        Session::flash('error', 'Bitte setzen Sie ihr Passwort!');
                        return Redirect::route('user.password.show');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $next($request);
                    }
                }else
                {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    });
}
```

I search a solution where i put the code once and i can use it for all my controller but i have no idea where the code can be written in.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You shouldn't be checking the route name in the middleware, you should have the middleware assigned to only the routes that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Laravel [Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware). Define a middleware that checks for the user status before passing the request to the controllers, than register your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middlewares;

class UserBlockedMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
         $user = \Auth::user();
         if($user->status == 'blocked') abort(403);

         return $next($request);

    }

}
```

To learn more on how to register a global middleware check this [section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware) in Laravel docs.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes)

You can attach `auth` middleware to routes you want to protect, or directly in the `__construct` of your controller

> Laravel ships with an auth middleware, which is defined at Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate

If you want your [own Auth middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) you can type the following

`php artisan make:middleware MyOwnAuth`

---

Also you can actually reduce the code like that

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        if (
            strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(), 'user.password.show') != 0
            && strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(), 'user.password.set') != 0
            && strcmp(Route::currentRouteName(), 'user.blocked.show') != 0
            && $this->user->status == Userstatus::where('type', 'passwordSetFalse')->first()->id
        ) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Bitte setzen Sie ihr Passwort!');
            return Redirect::route('user.password.show');
        };
        return $next($request);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!